Mongodb connection string error with VScode
I am trying to connect my .prisma file to my mongo db database but i got a p1013 error. It says the provided database string is invalid. I tried everything from changing the database password to creating a new mongodb with another email still have the same problem. my connection string is in the form mongodb+srv://:@/. I already looked through a few error issues that says to include a / test but it does not work. The connection string generated for vs code does not include anything after the / at the end of the string. I need help.
i run a command npx prisma db push to push a model i created to my mongodb data base and i expected it to work but i got the p1013 error.

share your .env file (not the exact links but similar to the original)
and your prisma schema file
